# Python image detection of shapes

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

I have one image with a various number of stars, circles, and other shapes. Shapes are in different color from the background.  Is there any way in Python to detect shapes on the image using Python scipy and numpy libraries?

Comment: please improve your question and provide some sample data, expected output etc.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV is what you need. OpenCV is an image processing (computer vision) lib.
Here is a shape detection [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/).

Comment: unfortunately, i am not able to use opencv, only numpy or scipy

Comment: @viktor.radovic, what is the limitation? I believe it is possible to detect shapes with `scipy` but it will be much more laborious than incorporation of sufficient dependency even there is dependency limitations.